# Terraform: Error: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: invalid configuration

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

After deleting kubernetes cluster with "terraform destroy" I can't create it again anymore.

"terraform apply" returns the following error message:

> Error: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: invalid configuration: no
> configuration has been provided, try setting KUBERNETES_MASTER
> environment variable

Here is the terraform configuration:

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "skyglass-msur"
    key    = "terraform/backend"
    region = "us-east-1"
  }
}

locals {
  env_name         = "staging"
  aws_region       = "us-east-1"
  k8s_cluster_name = "ms-cluster"
}

variable "mysql_password" {
  type        = string
  description = "Expected to be retrieved from environment variable TF_VAR_mysql_password"
}

provider "aws" {
  region = local.aws_region
}

data "aws_eks_cluster" "msur" {
  name = module.aws-kubernetes-cluster.eks_cluster_id
}

module "aws-network" {
  source = "github.com/skyglass-microservices/module-aws-network"

  env_name              = local.env_name
  vpc_name              = "msur-VPC"
  cluster_name          = local.k8s_cluster_name
  aws_region            = local.aws_region
  main_vpc_cidr         = "10.10.0.0/16"
  public_subnet_a_cidr  = "10.10.0.0/18"
  public_subnet_b_cidr  = "10.10.64.0/18"
  private_subnet_a_cidr = "10.10.128.0/18"
  private_subnet_b_cidr = "10.10.192.0/18"
}

module "aws-kubernetes-cluster" {
  source = "github.com/skyglass-microservices/module-aws-kubernetes"

  ms_namespace       = "microservices"
  env_name           = local.env_name
  aws_region         = local.aws_region
  cluster_name       = local.k8s_cluster_name
  vpc_id             = module.aws-network.vpc_id
  cluster_subnet_ids = module.aws-network.subnet_ids

  nodegroup_subnet_ids     = module.aws-network.private_subnet_ids
  nodegroup_disk_size      = "20"
  nodegroup_instance_types = ["t3.medium"]
  nodegroup_desired_size   = 1
  nodegroup_min_size       = 1
  nodegroup_max_size       = 5
}

# Create namespace
# Use kubernetes provider to work with the kubernetes cluster API
provider "kubernetes" {
  # load_config_file       = false
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(data.aws_eks_cluster.msur.certificate_authority.0.data)
  host                   = data.aws_eks_cluster.msur.endpoint
  exec {
    api_version = "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1"
    command     = "aws-iam-authenticator"
    args        = ["token", "-i", "${data.aws_eks_cluster.msur.name}"]
  }
}

# Create a namespace for microservice pods
resource "kubernetes_namespace" "ms-namespace" {
  metadata {
    name = "microservices"
  }
}
```

P.S. There seems to be the issue with terraform kubernetes provider for 0.14.7

I couldn't use "load_config_file" = false in this version, so I had to comment it, which seems to be the reason of this issue.

P.P.S. It could also be the issue with outdated cluster_ca_certificate, which terraform tries to use: deleting this certificate could be enough, although I'm not sure, where it is stored.

Comment: Can this issue be fixed without adding export KUBE_CONFIG_PATH=/path/to/.kube/config? I mean in case of, for example, AWS codepipeline it can not work.

Comment: @fireman777 Try this command:
aws eks --region ${var.region} update-kubeconfig --name ${var.cluster_name}


Make sure you have access to your AWS account inside AWS codepipeline. Make sure your AWS EKS cluster exists at the time of furnning the script.
Replace var.region and var.cluster_name with your own values.

Comment: Thanks, @Mykhailo Skliar for the help. By the way, I noticed a strange behavior: after upgrading to Terraform 0.15.5, my problem suddenly disappears.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Before doing something radical like manipulating the state directly, try setting the KUBE_CONFIG_PATH variable:

```
export KUBE_CONFIG_PATH=/path/to/.kube/config
```

After this rerun the `plan` or `apply` command.
This has fixed the issue for me.

Comment: for some reason my env had `KUBECONFIG` set instead which seemed to work - until recently. `KUBE_CONFIG_PATH` werks for me. cool!

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue. I even manually deleted the EKS cluster which really messed up the terraform state.

However, after wasting a few hours, I found out that there is a very simple solution.

You can run

```
terraform state rm <resource_type>.<resource_name>
```

I just executed

```
terraform state rm `terraform state list | grep eks`
```

to remove all the entries for a particular service from state file in a safe manner.

Comment: Thanks I solved my problem by
terraform state rm `terraform state list | grep eks`
terraform state rm `terraform state list | grep kubectl`
terraform state rm `terraform state list | grep helm`

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me when I was needed to make an update to the cluster that requires to delete some resources.
You can also try to run `terraform apply -refresh=false` and just let it destroy it.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting terraform state S3 bucket on AWS solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my case this error was occurring when I was trying to destroy resources with 'tf destroy'

The logical solution for me was to do the following action:

1. Run 'tf apply -refresh=true' on terraform state, where you bootstrap K8S cluster. This is the workspace, where you output K8S credentials (k8s_cluster_access_token)
2. Run 'tf apply -refresh=true' on terraform state, that is using above K8S credentials to create K8S resources.
3. Run 'tf destroy' (finished with success)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by using the [official `helm` provider](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-helm) instead of the `kubernetes` one.

First, we list the required providers:

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket  = "..."
    key     = "..."
    region  = "..."
    profile = "..."
  }

  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 4.49"
    }

    kubernetes = {
      source  = "hashicorp/kubernetes"
      version = "~> 2.16.1"
    }

    helm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/helm"
      version = "~> 2.8.0"
    }
  }
}
```

Then, we configure the provider:

```
data "aws_eks_cluster" "cluster" {
  name = var.cluster_name
}

provider "helm" {
  kubernetes {
    host                   = data.aws_eks_cluster.cluster.endpoint
    cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(data.aws_eks_cluster.cluster.certificate_authority.0.data)
    exec {
      api_version = "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1"
      command = "aws"
      args = [
        "eks",
        "get-token",
        "--cluster-name",
        data.aws_eks_cluster.cluster.name,
        "--profile",
        var.profile
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Finally, we add charts via the `helm_release` resources:

```
resource "helm_release" "foo" {
  name             = "foo"
  chart            = "foo"
  repository       = "https://foo.bar/chart"
  namespace        = "foo"
  create_namespace = true
  values           = [templatefile("${path.module}/chart/values.yaml", {})]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Deleting .terraform sub-folder in the folder where you run "terraform" command should also solve the issue.

I didn't try it for this exact situation, but I had a similar issue today, so I decided to share another solution. It seems less radical, than deleting S3 bucket.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this problem was that usually, I had something in my kubeconfig, but it was empty for some reason. Somewhat of a random fix, but when I reinitialized the config (I'm using Minikube as well, so I started minikube) Terraform was then happy.

I'm curious if using the aws command line to update the kubeconfig would work in your case. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/eks/update-kubeconfig.html

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know your **KUBECONFIG** path, use this command:

`aws eks --region ${var.region} update-kubeconfig --name ${var.cluster_name}`

- Make sure you have access to your AWS account inside your terraform (or any other script).
- Make sure your AWS EKS cluster exists at the time of running the
  script.
- Replace **var.region** and **var.cluster_name** with your own values.

You can even create terraform **null_resource**, which will automatically update your KUBECONFIG path:

```
resource "null_resource" "update_kubeconfig" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "aws eks --region ${var.region} update-kubeconfig --name ${var.cluster_name}"
  }
  depends_on = [your_kubernetes_cluster_resource]
}
```